# about mangled name of functions in c++

Tags: android, c++, function

ı have closed source shared library that links against libmedia.so from android

but unforunatly in >android 5.0 ABI changes that made by google broke my closed source lib (thanx google)

now ı have the following error --> `dlopen failed cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android11MediaPlayer13setDataSourceEPKcPKNS_11KeyedVectorINS_7String8ES4_EE" referenced by "mylib.so"`

then ı hexedited my closed source library(mylib.so) to load myhack.so (that ı built myself) instead of libmedia.so (so ı simply made a trick)

here is the Android.mk of myhack.so library:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hack.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libmedia
LOCAL_MODULE := myhack
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and here is the hack.cpp:

```
extern "C" void _ZN7android11MediaPlayer13setDataSourceERKNS_2spINS_17IMediaHTTPServiceEEEPKcPKNS_11KeyedVectorINS_7String8ES9_EE();
extern "C" void _ZN7android11MediaPlayer13setDataSourceEPKcPKNS_11KeyedVectorINS_7String8ES4_EE() {
    return _ZN7android11MediaPlayer13setDataSourceERKNS_2spINS_17IMediaHTTPServiceEEEPKcPKNS_11KeyedVectorINS_7String8ES9_EE();
}
```

let me explain a bit:

1-as I said I hexedited my closed source lib to load myhack.so instead of libmedia.so (source file and android.mk file of myhack.so are in above)

2-I linked myhack.so to libmedia.so(as you can see) to provide other libmedia functions via myhack.so

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libmedia
```

3-
lost symbol: `_ZN7android11MediaPlayer13setDataSourceEPKcPKNS_11KeyedVectorINS_7String8ES4_EE`

current symbol in libmedia.so: `_ZN7android11MediaPlayer13setDataSourceERKNS_2spINS_17IMediaHTTPServiceEEEPKcPKNS_11KeyedVectorINS_7String8ES9_EE`

so if lost symbol is called, it will return original function

my question is should I use extern "C" **void** or extern "C" **int**..... int or void? which one? setDataSource is a function and I dont think it is returning integer value so it should be **void** ı think but ım not %100 sure

could anyone help me please? thanx

Comment: This is just a bad idea from the get-go.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious yeah ı know but as ı said unfortunatly lib that I use is closed-source :( so I dont have so much option.ı could find this workaround(very hacky ı know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooner or later you will get in troble with it. I remember problems with skia on project I work on. Some vendors were doing small changes with interfaces and that was causing various crashes.

To find return type you can investigate sources for android, steps are below:

You can use https://demangler.com/, to see signature of your function, it should be:

```
android::MediaPlayer::setDataSource(android::sp<android::IMediaHTTPService> const&, char const*, android::KeyedVector<android::String8, android::String8> const*)
```

now lets search android sources for such signature, you can find it here:

http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmedia/mediaplayer.cpp#148

so its return type is `status_t`, which is `typedef int status_t;`, so as you have assumed its `int`.

Comment: thank you so much.. ı understood now..so return type should be "int" yep..will try it..